# Simple harmonic oscillator, calculate the trajectory in real space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, potential-energy

Potential of a simple harmonic oscillator: 
$$U=\frac{1}{2}k x^2$$

I'm asked to calculate the trajectory of a particle moving in this potential, with initial conditions $x(t=0) = 0$ and $v(t=0)=v_0$.

What exactly do they mean by "calculate the trajectory?" What sort of thing am I supposed to end up with?

Comment: What tools do you have? That is, have you learned Lagrangian or Hamiltonian dynamics, or is this for a Newtonian mechanics course?

Comment: This question leads on to calculating this trajectory in phase space, I'm just starting Hamiltonian dynamics

Comment: So basically the question is asking you to write out the Hamiltonian to find $dp/dt$ and $dx/dt$, then get $x(t)$ from that.

Answer (score 3):

"Calculate the trajectory" just means calculate $x(t)$, given the potential energy and the initial conditions.

Answer (score -3):

To calculate the trajectory means to find the relation between $v$, $\omega$, $A$, and $x$ in the $v$-$x$ coordinate system  which leads to the ellipsoid curve.